# Shiny app to show simulation: how to re-write using plotly

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

I have a simple prototype Shiny app that shows Brownian motion in 1D. Currently I use base graphics to get the minimum functionality I'm looking for.  When I scale this up to the actual task I'm interested in, each step in the simulation will be more computationally intensive (in this prototype it's along the lines of `x <- x + rnorm(1)`).

So I'm wondering if plotly can help with rendering efficiency, and if so how to do that.  From my minimal search it seems like these kind of cumulative animations in plotly require having the entire timeseries in hand and replicating it by frames: https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/. When each step of the simulation is costly, this will mean the user waits a long time for the app to render at all.  I would instead like to render the cumulative results "in real time" after each iteration of the simulation, as is currently implemented below using base graphics.  Any thoughts on how to convert this to plotly would be very helpful!  As one last challenge, I want to keep the "Go", "Stop", "Reset" buttons in the sidebar and not use plotly's animation buttons.

Thanks! (and thanks to @danyaalmohamed for an example that got this MWE started for me)

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(
    titlePanel('1D Brownian Motion'),
    sidebarLayout(
        # panel with all inputs
        sidebarPanel(
            # param set-up
            numericInput('mean', 'mean', 0, step = 1),
            numericInput('sd', 'sd', 1, step = 0.5, min = 0.0001),

            # buttons to start, stop, reset 
            fluidRow(
                column(3, actionButton('go', 'Go')),
                column(3, actionButton('stop', 'Stop')),
                column(3, actionButton('reset',label='Reset'))
            )
        ),

        # plot panel
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput('bmtrack', height = '250px'), 
            plotOutput('bmmax', height = '250px')
        )
    )
)

server<-function(input,output){
    waits <- reactiveValues() # reactive to store all reactive variables
    waits$x <- 0
    waits$xmax <- 0
    waits$tt <- 0

    # function to move simulation forward
    forward <- function() {
        waits$x <- c(waits$x, 
                            tail(waits$x, 1) + rnorm(1, input$mean, input$sd))
        waits$xmax <- c(waits$xmax, max(waits$x))
        waits$tt <- c(waits$tt, max(waits$tt) + 1)
    }

    # setup
    session <- reactiveValues()
    session$timer <- reactiveTimer(Inf)

    # when go button is pressed
    observeEvent(input$go,{
        session$timer<-reactiveTimer(30)
        observeEvent(session$timer(),{
            forward()
        })
    })


    # when stop button is pressed
    observeEvent(input$stop,{
        session$timer<-reactiveTimer(Inf)
    })


    # when reset button is pressed
    observeEvent(input$reset,{
        waits$x <- 0
        waits$xmax <- 0
        waits$tt <- 0
    })

    output$bmtrack<-renderPlot({
        ylim <- c(-1, 1)
        if(ylim[1] > min(waits$x)) ylim[1] <- min(waits$x)
        if(ylim[2] < max(waits$x)) ylim[2] <- max(waits$x)

        par(mar = c(3, 3, 2, 0) + 0.5, cex = 1.4, mgp = c(1.75, 0.5, 0), tcl = -0.25)
        plot(waits$tt, waits$x, 
             type = 'l', lwd = 2,
             ylab = 'X', xlab = '', main = 'BM track',
             xlim = c(0, ifelse(max(waits$tt) < 50, 50, max(waits$tt))),
             ylim = ylim)
    })

    output$bmmax<-renderPlot({
        ylim <- c(-1, 1)
        if(ylim[1] > min(waits$xmax)) ylim[1] <- min(waits$xmax)
        if(ylim[2] < max(waits$xmax)) ylim[2] <- max(waits$xmax)

        par(mar = c(3, 3, 2, 0) + 0.5, cex = 1.4, mgp = c(1.75, 0.5, 0), tcl = -0.25)
        plot(waits$tt, waits$xmax, 
             type = 'l', lwd = 2,
             ylab = 'max of X', xlab = 'Time', main = 'BM max',
             xlim = c(0, ifelse(max(waits$tt) < 50, 50, max(waits$tt))),
             ylim = ylim)
    })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For efficient changes to a plotly object you should take a look at [plotlyProxy](https://plot.ly/r/plotlyproxy/), which avoids re-rendering the entire plot. Here are some [streaming examples](https://plot.ly/r/streaming/).

Here is what I think you are after - btw. you sould avoid calling your `reactiveValues` "session", because `session` is an optional argument to the `server` function (which is needed for `plotlyProxy`).

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel('1D Brownian Motion'),
                sidebarLayout(
                  # panel with all inputs
                  sidebarPanel(
                    # param set-up
                    numericInput('mean', 'mean', 0, step = 1),
                    numericInput('sd', 'sd', 1, step = 0.5, min = 0.0001),

                    # buttons to start, stop, reset
                    fluidRow(
                      column(3, actionButton('go', 'Go')),
                      column(3, actionButton('stop', 'Stop')),
                      column(3, actionButton('reset', label = 'Reset'))
                    )
                  ),

                  # plot panel
                  mainPanel(
                    plotlyOutput('bmtrack', height = '250px'),
                    plotlyOutput('bmmax', height = '250px')
                  )
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # reactive to store all reactive variables
  waits <- reactiveValues(x = 0, xmax = 0, tt = 0, timer = reactiveTimer(Inf))

  # function to move simulation forward
  forward <- function() {
    waits$x <- waits$x + rnorm(1, input$mean, input$sd)
    waits$xmax <- max(waits$xmax, waits$x)
    waits$tt <- waits$tt + 1
  }

  # when go button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    waits$timer <- reactiveTimer(100)
    observeEvent(waits$timer(), {
      forward()
    })
  })

  # when stop button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$stop, {
    waits$timer <- reactiveTimer(Inf)
  })

  # when reset button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
      waits$x <- 0
      waits$xmax <- 0
      waits$tt <- 0
  })

  # generate initial "empty" plot
  initial_plot <- plot_ly(
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines',
    line = list(color = '#000000',
                width = 3)
  )

  # render initial plot and assign to both outputs
  output$bmmax <- output$bmtrack <- renderPlotly({
    input$reset # rerender when reset is pressed
    initial_plot
  })

  # create plotlyProxy objects for both plotly outputs
  bmtrack_proxy <- plotlyProxy("bmtrack", session)
  bmmax_proxy <- plotlyProxy("bmmax", session)

  # manipulate plots via plotlyProxy objects (without rerendering)
  observe({
      plotlyProxyInvoke(bmtrack_proxy, "extendTraces", list(x = list(list(waits$tt)), y = list(list(waits$x))), list(0))
  })

  observe({
      plotlyProxyInvoke(bmmax_proxy, "extendTraces", list(x = list(list(waits$tt)), y = list(list(waits$xmax))), list(0))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

[image: Result]

Comment: awesome answer, thanks for the solution and explanation about names and efficiency